# How to open/read files on different partition? C in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems, partitioning

From the command line, I want to do `cat` on a txt file on a different partition, how can I do that?

I mount the drive manually and from the command line, I type: (this case, abc.txt in f drive)

```
cat ~/media/f/abc.txt
```

But it says no such file or directory exists.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Remove the ~ and try again ;)

Comment: How exactly do you mount your drive? Could you please post your mounting command? What is an output of 'mount -l' command after you've done your mount operation?

Comment: ~ points to your local user directory, is it really the case?

Comment: I did not mount the drive in command line, I did in the graphical UI, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're writing `cat ~/media/f/abc.txt`, you are referringn to a directory called media inside your home folder. Are you sure you mounted it there, and not in `/media` ? Try this:

```
cat /media/f/abc.txt
```